# Application insights setAuthenticatedUserContext with API on another domain

Tags: cookies, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights configured on both the front and back-end of my website, which operate on different sub-domains (let's say `www.mydomain.com` and `api.mydomain.com`).

The cookie containing the user information set by `setAuthenticatedUserContext` is stored by AI with the cookie domain set to `www.mydomain.com`. When I make a call to `api.mydomain.com` the cookie is not included, and therefore the credentials I set are not associated with any AI data logged by the API.

My API has `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` set to `true`, and the front-end has `withCreditials` set to `true` on the XHR object.

Can I get AI to set a different cookie domain, or is there some other issue at play here stopping the user information reaching the API?

**Update:** I notice Google Analytics sets a cookie with the domain set simply to `.mydomain.com`, and this cookie information is included with calls to my API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported but there is an issue opened on GH for it: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/64
Please continue monitoring GH link, we will provide an update soon. Thanks!